# All non-redundant paths in a directed graph (DiGraph) from NetworkX . Python

Tags: python, matrix, network-programming, networkx, redundancy

I'm looking for a way to navigate directed graphs to find the building blocks of the graph. `NetworkX` has `all_simple_paths` that finds all paths between `source` and `target` nodes.  What I would like to do is similar, but to find not exactly the same.  *An unbiased decomposition of a network into minimal units*

This directed network `H` below, is built on the following paths:

```
#Non-redundant paths
['A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'F']
['A', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'F']
['G','C','E','F']
```

**What is the most efficient way in Python to find these paths?** Would navigating through `nx.adjacency_matrix(H).toarray()` be the way to do it?

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

H = nx.DiGraph()

nodes = list("ABCDEFG")
edges = [("A","B"),("B","C"),("B","D"),("C","E"),("D","E"),("E","F"),("G","C")]
H.add_nodes_from(nodes)
H.add_edges_from(edges)
coords = {"A":(-2,0),"B":(-1,0),"C":(0,1),"D":(0,-1),"E":(1,0),"F":(2,0),"G":(0,2)}
nx.draw(H,pos=coords,with_labels=True)

paths = nx.all_simple_paths(H, source="A", target="F") 

for path in paths: print(path)    
#['A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'F']
#['A', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'F']
```

Comment: How are the paths you've listed *not* the sum of two other paths? You can split any of them into two paths at any intermediate vertex.

Comment: you're right, fixing it now. sorry about that!